# Application to make video out of frames with a given frame rate?

Tags: video, images, video-editing

I have frames extracted from video with 24 fps (I used ffmpeg), now I need to glue them back with the same frame rate. It should be free, preferably for Linux, but Windows or Android are also acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use ffmpeg also?

> For creating a video from many images:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i foo-%03d.jpeg foo.avi
```

*edit: removed the -f image2 format as it is now optional, ffmpeg takes the format as guess from the input filename, but its still supported in case your filename does not have extension.*

The syntax foo-%03d.jpeg specifies to use a decimal number composed of three digits padded with zeroes to express the sequence number. It is the same syntax supported by the C printf function, but only formats accepting a normal integer are suitable.

Comment: I've got problem: 'Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mjpeg, none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown)): unspecified size'. I tried to use '-c:v <codec>' but it always tells 'unknown decoder'.

Comment: What format are  your images?  if they are not jpeg you should change the example to reflect the proper codec (as ffmpeg will try to guess the input codec from the file extension) or force it to use your image format by using  "ffmpeg -framerate 24   -c:v jpeg  -i foo-%03d.jpeg foo.avi" change your codec and file extensions accordingly also, try specifying your output codec (use -c:v libx264 before the filename and use foo.mp4 as filename)